# @Retryable -> value property doesn't work as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

I'm having a weird problem with @Retryable annotation.

It suppose to be fired only with the defined exception classes on **value** property:

```
@Retryable(value = {IllegalArgumentException.class}, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50))
```

But, it's being fired with any exception:

```
org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Cannot locate recovery method; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 : "{"timestamp":"2021-11-13T16:46:32.842+00:00", ---SO ON---
```

All documents I see, says, only work with exceptions indicated on **value** property.

Any ideas?

Kind regards

**EDITED:**

By ask of @Hans-Christian this are the code:

```
@Retryable(value = {IllegalArgumentException.class}, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50))
public ResponseEntity<Object> subscriptionGet(UUID subscriptionId){
    ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.getForEntity(USER_SUBSCRIPTION_GET_ID_URL, SubscriptionResponse.class, subscriptionId);
    return response;
}

@Recover
public ResponseEntity<Object> recoverSubscriptionGet(IllegalArgumentException e, UUID subscriptionId){
    log.error("Unable to reach service: {}", e.getMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
}
```

In case of other kind of Exception, like `HttpClientErrorException.Forbidden` the **retry fires** and lost great deal of time, trying to find this **Recover**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message `Cannot locate recovery method` it looks like you added the annotation `@Recover` on another method with a different return value.

If that's the case, either align the return value of your `@Recover` method to be the same as the method with the @Retryable annotation or remove the recover-method.

Example:

```
  @Retryable(value = {IllegalArgumentException.class}, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50))
  private String doSomething() throws Exception {
      // return value is a String
  }

  @Recover
  void recoverSomething(IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // this method does not return a String
  }
```

Comment: It's not the case, there is only one `@Retryable` and only one `@Recover`.

The point is, this retry happen, independently of Exception class defined on value, and I only want to retry if this are the case (IllegalArgumentException only).

Comment: ok, can you share the code how the Retryable and Recover methods are defined?

Comment: Shared @Hans-Christian